# How to use Hammer JS carousel with Knockout bindings

Tags: css, knockout.js, hammer.js

Standard Hammer JS carousel but with knockout, displays carousel pages stacked below each other, How to get this displaying properly with Knockout, any ideas ?

```
<ul data-bind=" foreach: Stories, visible: Stories().length > 0" >
      <li data-bind=" css:  Pane">
      <p data-bind="html: Headline" />
       <p data-bind="html: subheading" />
     <h2>Swipe...</h2>
</li>
</ul>
```

works if we remove knockout bindings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dom issue binding too early

moved this from script to after calling my viewmodel binding

```
var carousel = new Carousel("#carousel");
carousel.init();
```

at the bottom of this demo view-source:http://rawgit.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/1.1.3/tests/manual/carousel.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but when using knockout you need to use empty tags not self closing ones.  So give this a try.

```
<ul data-bind=" foreach: Stories, visible: Stories().length > 0" >
    <li data-bind=" css:  Pane">
      <p data-bind="html: Headline"></p>
      <p data-bind="html: subheading"></p>
     <h2>Swipe...</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks Nathan UL was missing in my post , found the problem, smelt like a dom issue (init) was being called way to early, i've put it in as answer